# Cookies Warning Placement In React Router App?

Tags: reactjs, cookies, react-router

I would like to display a cookies warning that takes up the full page with a modal but shows up on each page of the site (if cookies haven't been accepted)

I have wired up redux to store the value of whether cookies have been accepted, and it pulls the choice from localStorage when the cookies component is loaded.

how do I get it so that the cookies component show up on each page without just adding in the code to each page, I could do that, but it seems like there must be a better way...

**This is the last thing I have tried:**

```
function App() {
    // let cookiesInit = localStorage.getItem('cookies');
    // if (cookiesInit == null) {

    return (
        <Provider store={store}>
            <Router history={history}>
                <React.Fragment>
                    <Cookies>
                        <Switch>
                            <Route path="/" exact component={HomePage} />
                            <Route path="/weather" exact component={Weather} />
                            <Route path="/superherosmackdown" exact component={VersionTwo} />
                            <Route path="/dicegame" exact component={DiceGame} />
                            <Route path="/dice" exact component={Dice} />
                            {/* <Route path="/AnastaciaKorotkevich" exact component={Nastya} /> */}
                            {/* <Route path="/learn" exact component={understandState} /> */}
                            <Route path="*" exact component={My404Component} />
                        </Switch>
                    </Cookies>
                </React.Fragment>
            </Router>
        </Provider>
    );
}

export default App;
```

```
import React from 'react';

import { CookiesCon } from './CookiesStyle';

export default function Cookies() {
    function agreeToCookies() {
        window.localStorage.setItem('cookies', 'yes');
    }

    function showModal() {
        let el = document.getElementById('more');
        el.style.display = 'block';
    }

    function refuseCookies() {
        window.localStorage.setItem('cookies', 'no');
        // this.props.agreeCookies('no');
    }

    //1. Test for empty localstorage
    //2. render based on cookie selection
    document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden';

    return (
        <CookiesCon>
            <div>
                <h1 className="full">
                    Yo, I use C
                    <span role="img" aria-label="cookies">
                        
                    </span>
                    K I E S
                </h1>
                <h3>
                    In order to give you the best experience possible, I use cookies.
                </h3>
                <h3>That cool?</h3>

                <button onClick={agreeToCookies}>
                    Yes, that's C
                    <span role="img" aria-label="cookies">
                        
                    </span>
                    L
                </button>
            </div>
        </CookiesCon>
    );
}
```

Comment: what is `Cookies` component? what is her purpose?

Comment: added it to the question

Comment: i dont see why all the `Route`s component should be children of `Cookies` component.
you should make `Cookies` component as standalone component Modal and add it alongside `Router` component(under `Provider`). this way you will able to see `Cookies` component in every page.